# RubyonRails wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, argument-error

I am not a Ruby developer but I have an application that I inherited that runs on it.  I am getting the below error:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

Code having problem is:

```
def destroy
   @user.destroy(params[:id]) #This is the line that my ArgumentError pointed to
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
     format.json { head :no_content }
   end
end
```

Any update to code or other places I need to look would be much appreciated.

I tried removing the (params) but that ended up creating other issue.
I have read through other posts and did not see one using params

Comment: `@user.destroy` is how to do it - *but that ended up creating other issue* - you fix that one too. note: class method: `User.destroy(1)`, instance method: `@user = User.find(1); @user.destroy`.

Comment: What was the other issue when you removed the params ? There's a big chance that `@user.destroy` does not take any argument... Post the other issue with the relevant code (this is far from enough to help you)

Answer (score 1):

`destroy` takes no paramaters. You're already calling it on the instance variable.

```
@user.destroy
```

You may be confusing the [class method](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy) with the [instance method](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: Its a class method